# what are the restricitons of the type of a default parameter in C++

Tags: c++, default-parameters

```
void foo(Type1 a, Type2 b = value2)
```

May I know what are the restrictions of Type2 to be a parameter that accepts default value?  I reckon value2 of type2 should be decidable at compile time. 
For example, an integer. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Any types and constant conversions need to be seen at compile time in [tag:c++].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a lot of flexibility. `value2` needs to be an expression which is valid at the point of declaration of the function (by "valid" I mean that the names it uses are in scope, etc), and its type must be implicitly convertible to `Type2`, same as for any initializer. `value2` is evaluated each time the function is called. So for example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int i;

void foo(std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>(i)) {
    std::cout << v.size() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    i = 1;
    foo();
    i = 2;
    foo();
}
```

With the right initializer, `Type2` can even be a reference type:

```
void bar(int &j = i);
```

Comment: ok I see. So basically the default value can be something that is evaluated at runtime and will be evaluated at runtime everytime that function gets called?

Comment: @KKKoo0. Yes. Try declaring a global `int i` and using `i++` as a default value.

Answer (score 1):

`value2` must be compile-time convertible to `Type2`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes correct.

The only limitation is defaulted variable should be last one.  You can have multiple default variables just make sure keep them all at the end.  Don't mix with non default ones.